# Can I change the look of my terminal when I run a program?

Tags: c#, formatting

I am learning C# and I am tryin to print a list of names in my terminal but they all come out on to one line.

Code:

```
List<string> employees = new List<string>() { "adam", "amy" };
      employees.Add("barbara");
      employees.Add("barbara");

      for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
      {
        Console.Write(employees[i]);
      }
```

terminal:
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxJgB.jpg)

How do I change my terminal to look better and print each name and future objects on to separate lines so that way I am able to read it better?

What I tried doing was downloading a formatter and also changed the settings in the settings.json and expected the list of names to come out like [expected terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6nfL.jpg)

Comment: `Console.Write` -> `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: You can `Console.WriteLine("something")` instead of `Console.Write("something")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-7.0):

> Writes the specified data, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream.